# Facebook Graph API: result in array or in json object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have little bit confuse between graph api result.Can any one explain which default object method is facebook using when we fetch data via graph api. Have any application account setting for access data in json object or in array object, because some time i found user data in encrypted and some time non encrypted.
I found user email id in two way from facebook graph api.
One is:

```
{
   "id": "100001114785800",
   "name": "Stella Jackson",
   "first_name": "Stella",
   "last_name": "Jackson",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100001114785800",
   "birthday": "04/16/1987",
   "gender": "female",
   "email": "stella_ja@live.com",
   "timezone": 5.5,
   "locale": "en_US",
   "updated_time": "2010-10-08T13:26:10+0000"
}
```

And second one is:

```
{
   "id": "100001114785800",
   "name": "Stella Jackson",
   "first_name": "Stella",
   "last_name": "Jackson",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100001114785800",
   "birthday": "04/16/1987",
   "gender": "female",
   "email": "stella_ja\u0040live.com",
   "timezone": 5.5,
   "locale": "en_US",
   "updated_time": "2010-10-08T13:26:10+0000"
}
```

Have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Any JSON parser should read both those emails as the same. \u0040 is just the escaped version of the at-sign.

Answer (score 1):

The '\u0040' is same as obfuscated or Unicode form of '@' symbol. Most Parsers can convert that to the original symbol.

Check this for list of Unicode character set.

http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html

Comment: I am fetching facebook user information on my site last 2 month, it returned the user email like 'stella_ja@live.com' but suddenly two day ago facebook provide email with Unicode like 'stella_ja\u0040live.com'. This issue give error on my registration page for invalid email. I have solved this error to parse facebok return data in json_decode, But i want to know why suddenly i get user email with Unicode character from facebook. Why???

Comment: Thats a big why.. but i dont know why.. i tried with a sample app and i still got the proper emailID no unicodes..

Answer (score 1):

@Vik i want to do the same thing, collect post info in array, try this if it work than see..

```
   if (response.authResponse) {
    var accessToken =    response.authResponse.accessToken;
        //var UserInfo = document.getElementById('UserInfo'); 
        FB.api('/' + info.id + '/feed?access_token=' + accessToken, 
                    { limit: 20 },function(result) {

        UserInfo.innerHTML = "Welcome, " +  result.id + "!";
        alert('Message: ' + result.id);
            });
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the dictionary n value of email for ios

```
FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me" withGetVars:nil];
NSLog(@"getMeButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);
NSDictionary *dictionary=[fb_graph_response.htmlResponse JSONValue];
NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary valueForKey:@"email"]);
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to take the email string and do something like this (objective c):

```
NSString *email = @"stella_ja\u0040live.com"; // or whatever you use to get it
email = [NSString stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"\u0040" withString:@"@"];
```

So in other words, **use string methods to replace "\u0040" with "@".**

Answer (score 0):

you can simply replace `\u0040` with `@` but during this replace compiler will consider `"\"` as escape sequence and will skip this without making changes.

What you do like this below:

```
NSString *strEmail = @"stella_ja\u0040live.com";
[strEmail stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\u0040" withString:@"@"];
NSLog(@"strEmail: %@", strEmail);
```